# Angular Directives with External Controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am following this blog post in creating directives: http://joelhooks.com/blog/2014/02/11/lets-make-full-ass-angularjs-directives/

He seemed to recommend having the controller seperate from the directive. However trying to run a function from the external controller in the link function results in undefined is not a function.

Controller

```
wrmcControllers.controller 'voteCtrl', ($scope,$attrs) ->
   this.hasVoted = false
   this.init = ->
     if this.hasVoted
       #scope.vote = Vote.get(scope.vote)
     else
       this.vote = null

   this.voteUp = ->
     if this.vote == true
       this.vote = null
     else
       this.vote = true
       this.hasVoted = true

   this.voteDown = ->
     if this.vote == false
       this.vote = null
     else
       this.vote = false
       this.hasVoted = true
```

Directive

```
 wrmcDirectives.directive 'voteSet', ->
   restrict: 'AE'
   scope: {}
   controller: 'voteCtrl'
   templateUrl: 'vote.html'
   link: (scope,element,attrs,controller) ->
     console.log controller
     controller.init()
```

Console.log controller output

```
function () {
      if (this.vote === false) {
        return this.vote = null;
      } else {
        this.vote = false;
        return this.hasVoted = true;
      }
    }
```

Comment: init function seems to be attached to scope not on the controller instance... Change `$scope.init` to `this.init`

Comment: If you want to initialize your controller, I would like to suggest you should call the init method in your controller code itself.

Comment: the $scope.init was just from me tryin different stuff but I switched it back to this.init this has no effect on the outcome.

Comment: something seems odd with your controller; your console log output isn't showing the entire controller, rather it is showing the last function `voteDown` as if that is the entire object.

Comment: I know im confused about that

Comment: I'm no expert with CoffeeScript, but I would think this isn't an angular issue, rather a compile issue within the CoffeeScript.  Try writing the controller as a traditional JavaScript element and verify it functions, then try to determine why your CoffeeScript version is coming out mangled.

Comment: no the coffeescript is fine

Comment: I set up a minimum demo that I try to write as a plain javascript not CoffeeScript.
It seems to work properly.
What is the difference between this demo and your code?
[demo at jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yazaki/a4hcg5Lo/3/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you can do (you try, am not sure) :)

```
{
   controller:....,
   controllerAs: "myctrl",
   link : function($scope) {
        $scope.myctrl.init()
   }
}
```

Your example controller above, i think is for "require" (the required directive's controller).

Comment: can you show me a plunker or something. i know it should.

Answer (score 0):

I tried with traditional javascript, there is no problem, so it is better to check the broswer console to see if any runtime error with you code.

Comment: I have been checking the console of course, i would have included any relevant errors if that were the case